# Can I make a Moose attribute "write once"?

Tags: perl, moose

I would like to have a non-required Moose attribute that can be set only once.

If I use `is => 'ro'` I must set the attribute upon creation of the object, but I want to be able to add it afterwards (as long as it's not been set already).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[MooseX::SetOnce](http://p3rl.org/MooseX%3a%3aSetOnce)

Answer (score 5):

Use a method modifier:

```
has 'attr' => (
    is => 'rw',
    predicate => 'is_set',
    ...
};   

before 'attr' => sub {
     my $self = shift;
     die 'attr already set' if $self->is_set;
};
```

Comment: you would use 'around' to stop the method call that way you dont have to die

Comment: also do not use die, please never use die, die is evil and should die. use croak, or confess instead.

Comment: qodeninja: it depends.  You might want do bail out and let the caller trap it.

Comment: xenoterracide: it depends.  There *are* valid reasons to use `die`.